# Antonym for purist?

Tags: antonyms

Does a word exist that could accurately be used as an antonym for 'purist', which is *a person who insists on absolute adherence to traditional rules or structures, especially in language or style.*

I got stuck mid-sentence looking for an appropriate fill, and ended up with an ungratifying conclusion to an argument because nothing came to mind.

Edit: Not sure if context matters much here, but by using purist, I'm specifically referring to someone who's a stickler for guidelines and rules, where sometimes discretion may be warranted.

Comment: Context *does* matter! ***Always**!* For example, in some contexts, @DjinTonic's ***maverick*** might be exactly what's needed. But in other contexts, words like ***pragmatist, utilitarian,...*** would be much more suitable. And I doubt any thesaurus would list ***maverick + pragmatist*** as synonyms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Duly noted! And regarding _utilitarian_, THAT is exactly what I was looking for. If I'd put more thought into the OP, I wouldn't have asked for an antonym per se. I was looking for something not so extreme as an antonym, and _utilitarian_ fits the bill rather nicely. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if you're a native Anglophone or not - but I am, and from what you say I suspect ***pragmatist*** is probably your best bet. Interestingly, Google NGrams tells me [***utilitarian*** is far more common than ***pragmatist***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pragmatist%2Cutilitarian&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpragmatist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cutilitarian%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpragmatist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cutilitarian%3B%2Cc0), BUT...

Comment: ...when applied as a "label" for a type of person, [***he's a utilitarian*** is too rare to even show on a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%27s+a+pragmatist%2Che%27s+a+utilitarian&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), whereas ***he's a pragmatist*** is perfectly common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am a native Anglophone; and I would certainly agree that _pragmatist_ is more commonly used. However, when reviewing the definition for _utilitarianism_, as opposed to the definition for _pragmatic_,  _pragmatist_ or _pragmatism_, it seems _utilitarianist_ is a better fit for my particular need. Although the two in their noun form are labelled as synonyms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**maverick** (n.)

> A person who refuses to follow the customs or rules of a group
>
> *He's always been a (bit of a) maverick in the world of fashion.*
>
> *political mavericks [=nonconformists]*
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maverick)

> An unorthodox or independent-minded person; a person who refuses to
> conform to the views of a particular group or party; an individualist.
> Also in extended use. OED

---

> They celebrated the operator as ingenious, independent, and subversive
> — a **maverick** who flouts the rules and blithely transgresses social
> boundaries. [Joan Roberts; *Cracked: How Telephone Operators Took on Canada's Largest Corporation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cracked/uGzCBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22maverick%20who%20flouts%20the%20rules%22%22&pg=PT46&printsec=frontcover)

> The **maverick** "grammatical" reflections in *How to Write* have
> hardly anything to do with everybody's grammar, which is more than once sacrificed in the text. They hint at a grammar of invention, of literary language as
> understood by Stein. Writing for her had "nothing to do with the human
> speech." [Claudia Franken; *Gertrude Stein, Writer and Thinker*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gertrude_Stein_Writer_and_Thinker/8PmpCutXS-EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=maverick%20%20grammar&pg=PA266&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Excellent suggestion! And certainly correct. Can I trouble you for another inquiry? Perhaps a word between the two; someone not quite a maverick, nor a purist, but rather a person willing to float off the rez when the situation permits. A person of discretion, if you will.

Comment: There may be many. Perhaps *nonconformist, daredevil, risk-taker*. It might depend on how often they go off the rez.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially where I ended up. However, I hadn't thought of maverick, which is a great word for where I was going. Thanks!

Comment: There’s also just a pragmatist. They’ll do what it takes regardless of whether it’s conformist or non-conformist.